The absorption of infrared light for regular materials, like fabric wallets backpacks and clothes
I work as a brand partner for a company that produces a patch which strengthens the production of stemcells in the body.
The patches are activated with the help of the bodys own infrared radiation.
I do wanna carry the product with me but I do want to protect it from infrared radiation so that the patches do not loose its power when not used.
What are the absorption of infrared light for different fabric materials... For example a thicker fabric like the one of a wallet might absorb quite a lot? The one of the back of a backpack... The fabric there is quite thick right and I know if I would hold it in front of a fire a lot of the heat radiation would go away ... So it should work to have them stored in my backpack right?
Do these special rfid wallets protect from infrared radiation as well?
Thank you for your kind answers.
I wish you all a beautiful day!

Can you tell us how the patch works? As far as I can tell from your description, the whole thing is nonsense. I have never heard of a way to stimulate stem cell production in the body. If there was a way, it would likely involve drugs. Does the patch contain drugs? It is hard to imagine a drug, or anything else that needs to be activated by the body's IR radiation that wouldn't be activated by the IR radiation from the environment. You need a refrigerator to reduce IR radiation, not an absorbent material.

I'm no biochemist, but increasing stem cell production sounds like a straight road into cancer city.
